# Dynamic init to variable in a npm package

Tags: javascript, npm

I have an imported library from npm and some parts of it need to be initialized before use, a simplified version of the code in the library:

```
export let locale = () => { throw new Error("Must init locale"); }

export initLocale(userLocaleFunction) {
    locale = userLocaleFunction;
}
export checkLocale() {
    console.log(locale());
}
```

But when calling the library in the following way:

```
lib = require("lib");
lib.initLocale(() => { return "en" });
lib.checkLocale(); // works as expected: "en"
lib.locale(); // Throws "Must init locale";
```

`lib.locale` acts as if it's not been initialized. I can't have `initLocale()` return the locale, I need it to be on the variable `lib.locale`

Is it possible to initialize a variable in this way?

Comment: Try to change "let" for "const". Indeed, let is a scope limited declaration.  also you reassign locale inside initLocale so maybe it's just overriden

Comment: do you have control over the imported package ?

Comment: @Vinz243
I have control over it - I am migrating it from older js versions - that means a lot of the code relies on the lib.locale to look the way it does

Comment: @Webwoman I've edited the post to highlight the problem more clearly - I do initialize the variable and expect it to return "en" but instead I get the initial value - "Must init locale"

Comment: have you tried to change `let` for `var`?

Comment: @Webwoman I have, same result..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when initializing a variable inside a library it's only in the libraries scope.

In my first solution I simply returned the value:

```
export initLocale(userLocaleFunction) {
    locale = userLocaleFunction;
    return locale;
}
```

But then realized that this creates a new problem: What if locale gets modified inside the library, or worse, outside of it?

In the spirit of avoiding 2 sources of truth I ended up going with this:

```
locale = undefined;
export initLocale(userLocaleFunction) {
    locale = userLocaleFunction;
}
export getLocale() {
    if (locale === undefined) {
        throw new Error("Uninitialized locale");
    }
    return locale;
}
```

This code performs the `is initialized` check I needed at first and gives the value with one source of truth.